# Determine the slope of a plane whose rise in z is zero, but whose change in x and y are not.

Tags: 3d, plane-geometry, slope

Determine the slope of a plane whose rise in z is zero, but whose change in x and y are not. Explain what this plane looks like.

Would it be a plane in the xy plane? Not sure how to start this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The condition means that $z=k$ which represent all the planes parallel to $x-y$ plane.

Comment: How do I calculate the slope? If the rise is 0, wouldn't z=0?

Comment: @Donna In general we for a plane we have $z=ax+by+c$ and since $z=const.$ we have $a=b=0$ that is $z=c$.

Comment: Since it is parallel to the xy plane, then the slope of the plane is 0, right?

Comment: @Donna Yes exactly! Since $z=c$ for any x,y the slope with respect to z is zero.